# How to add image to button control in Smart device application?

Tags: c#, image, smartphone

I am developing smart device application in C#. I am not getting how to add image to button control in smart device application. Please make sure that all the functions of the .net framework does not work in .net compact framework. Can u provide me the code or link through which I can resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just click on  http://www.resco.net/developer/support/samples_imagebutton.aspx

Edit: the link is dead